# Oracle SQL: Temporary_table is out of sync with original_table

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

PROBLEM:

- Temporary_table is out of sync with original_table

SITUATION:

- Original table_has large datasets (10-30 million records daily) and 700+ fields
- Original_table is created/maintained by a vendor, and we may not be informed when fields are deleted/added/modified
- Temporary_table is used in stored procedures for DQ efforts
- Create temp_table SQL:

  CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE schema.temp_table ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
  AS SELECT * FROM schema.original_table WHERE 1=0;
- Insert Records into temp_table:

  INSERT INTO schema.temp_table SELECT * FROM schema.original_table PARTITION(partitionVal);
  ***NOTE**: partitionVal would be replaced with a date value (IE: p20_05_2022)*

QUESTION:

- Is it possible to create a DB trigger to re-create temporary_table when original_table is modified?
- If not, is there another option for re-creating temporary_table dynamically?
- Other than manually plugging into the Insert_SQL the names of all the known/expected fields, does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: tat sounds like a materialized view would be better https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

Comment: Not sure if that would work.  I need to be able to 
*** load data for partition a ... run my analysis ... dump the data
*** load data for partition b ... run my analysis ... lather rinse repeat.

Would I be able to do that with a materialized view?

Comment: The use case is not clear. How will you handle changing structure in your *analysis*? Do you really need a temporary table, why not just query the original table? Will this table be accessed only by a single session? Maybe you may just create this table each time you need to access it, especially with `on commit delete rows`?

Comment: yes you can partitio it https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/advanced-materialized-views.html#GUID-43FA865F-8C02-4B99-9202-49728BAA7687 but you sould read more in the manual

Comment: astentx -- I can certainly query the original table, but the query takes an inordinate amount of time (see original post:  Original table has large datasets (10-30 million records daily) and 700+ fields).  When running my series of queries against the original table, it completes in 4 hours.  Whereas running against the temp table, the series of queries complete in 30-45 min.

Comment: nbk -- The original table does have partitions, and the query to populate the temp table already uses that, in order to speed up the queries.  My question is more centered around re-creating the temp table, due to the vendor making changes to the original table structure (adding columns, changing datatypes, etc).  More specifically, the error is that when trying to run the insert the records into the temp table, I get an error due to those changes (insert into ... select * )